# Does happy allow single-line comments?

Tags: haskell, happy

Is there a way to comment everything to the end of the line, like `--` in Haskell? The only comment syntax I could find was the `{- commented stuff -}` syntax.

Comment: Ofcourse happy allows that, since ghc is written via Happy. :)

Comment: You should try it and find out; and if you have a Happy program with single line comments which doesn't compile, then post that program and the error.

Comment: Ah, great! I assumed that since the file extension is `.y` and since Happy is based on yacc, that the comment syntax would be C-like (`/* */` and `//`). If one of you would like to answer the question, I'll mark it as correct!